# Conditional Piecewise Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, conditional-statements, piecewise

This might be easier to explain by providing my attempt so far, then my intent+comments.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, arcsin, arcsinh

# Returns roots of quadratic (or lack of)
def roots(a, b, c):
    b24ac = b*b - 4*a*c
    if a == 0 or b24ac < 0:
        return np.nan, np.nan
    else:
        l = (-b - sqrt(b24ac))/(2*a)
        r = (-b + sqrt(b24ac))/(2*a)
        if l > r:
            l, r = r, l
        return l, r

# Some numeric functions
def pw1(z, a, b, c):
    return -arcsin((2*a*z+b)/sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c))/sqrt(-a)

def pw2(z, a, b, c):
    return arcsinh((2*a*z+b)/sqrt(4*a*c - b*b))/sqrt(a)

# Function incorporating above definitions w/ conditions/domains
def func(z, a, b, c):
    b24ac = b*b - 4*a*c
    l, r = roots(*abc)
    conditions = [(b24ac > 0 and a < 0) and (l < z and z < r),
                  (b24ac < 0 and a > 0)]
    choices = [pw1(z, a, b, c), 
               pw2(z, a, b, c)] 
    return np.select(conditions, choices)
```

This is my attempt at creating a python function that is a conditional piecewise function. For the mathematically curious, this is a portion of a full definition of the integral of $[ax^2+bx+c]^{-1/2}$. The necessary specifics are that I need a function that is conditional on the domain AND other parameters. I've looked into numpy's `piecewise` and `select` functions. `Piecewise`, for its condition list, only accepts logic on the domain (not the parameters). Unless I'm missing something, this seems like it won't work for me. `Select` has given me the most success. The only issues I've had are it not evaluating domain conditions, over its domain:

```py
--->  conditions = [(b24ac > 0 and a < 0) and (l < z and z < r),
                  (b24ac < 0 and a > 0)]

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Lastly, it evaluates all choices (which are results as opposed to the *functions* that you give `piecewise`), then selects the one per the conditions list to return (commenting out the `and (l < z`... conditions):

```py
c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:6: 
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
```

I started this weeks ago with a bunch of `elif` statements. This worked only for floats, not arrays. I'm using numpy, and having this function (or any really) evaluate over a domain is what I'm after. I then learned about `piecewise` and `select` and began playing with these, being from numpy.

I'd really like a pythonic way to do this. One that evaluates over numpy arrays, and only for the desired condition/domain. So, behaves like `piecewise` but has versatile conditioning like `select`. Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you better explain what conditions and choices are doing?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh for inputs I have the domain ```z``` and the parameters ```a, b, c```. Being the aforementioned integral, if the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ >= 0, it's undefined. This corresponds to conditions between ```z``` and the polynomials roots ```l``` and ```r```. So, this is the more piecewise part of it. Now depending on what ```a, b, c``` are, the mathematical form change, hence this being conditional as well.

Comment: So if I am understanding this right condition will be true only if those parameters you indicated are true, else false and do nothing?

Comment: For any other set of combinations, ```NaN``` is fine. In fact, ```select``` defaults to this (not that I need ```select``` to be the weapon of choice).

Answer (score 0):

The `b24ac` identifier is certainly descriptive,
but most folks would probably name it `discriminant`.

## use your own

You are complaining that you know how to compute the desired result,
but the numpy tools at hand don't seem a good fit.
So write your own function `fn` and use `.apply(fn)`, or [nditer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#broadcasting-array-iteration).
Notice that you can arrange for all needed arguments to appear in extra columns,
and have the function handle a row at a time.

I heard no concerns about speed,
which would be the usual argument against such a custom function.

## use np.piecewise

I agree with you that [piecewise()](https://numpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) appears to be appropriate to your needs.
The aspect that seemed missing was tailoring your functions with four parameters
before passing them to piecewise.
A good match for that need would be [functools.partial()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into these. I'm especially curious about the first option. It seems like this is a way 'numpify' regular code? If so, that'd open up 3-or-so close solutions I have to operation.

Comment: In pandas it's called iterrows(). Your function gets to operate on a whole row at a time, and produce whatever output value it wishes, row-by-row. Typically you would produce a new column, based on existing ones. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html